# Unable to use google "Places" in meteor

Tags: google-maps, meteor, google-places-api, google-places

I tried doing both:

`Template.unitMapView.onRendered(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load({ v: "3", libraries: "geometry, places"});
});`

and

```
Template.unitMapView.onCreated(function() {
GoogleMaps.load({ v: "3", libraries: "geometry, places"});
});
```

but still I am getting "undefined" for "google.maps.places" in my console, What am I missing?

Comment: The load is async. You can load what you need on startup and use the reactive `GoogleMaps.loaded()` reactive function where appropriate, assuming you are using `dburles:google-maps`. It's all in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, I was using GoogleMaps.load(), from some other file too. Removing this, I got the places library.